# How populate Expandable TableView itens and chields from SQLite with iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview, expandable

I need to create a ExpandableTableView on iOS and fill the items and sub ​​items SQLite

I search in Github and has not found

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried, and indicate what part of it you're having a problem with?

Comment: Thanks for your attention rickerby. I need understand if has how create this... If has how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to coding on iOS try implementing something already made by others.
Here is a good example: [HVTableView for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hvtableview)

The SQLite part is widely covered in the docs as Core Data. Try starting over here:
[iOS Developer Libraryi](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)